# BroadcastReceiver doesnt work, wrong Context (receiving calls)?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sip

Here is part of SipDemo (voip receiving calls) :

```
public class WalkieTalkieActivity extends Activity {
...
public IncomingCallReceiver callReceiver;
public SipManager manager = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

...

     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);


    initializeManager();
}

public void initializeManager() {
    initializeLocalProfile();
}

public void initializeLocalProfile() {

        SipProfile.Builder builder = new SipProfile.Builder(username, domain);
        builder.setPassword(password);
        me = builder.build();

        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, i, Intent.FILL_IN_DATA);
        manager.open(me, pi, null);
```

And BroadCastReceiver

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    try {

        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
        };

        WalkieTalkieActivity wtActivity = (WalkieTalkieActivity) context;
        incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);

        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
    ...

        wtActivity.call = incomingCall;
```

It works nice, but I need to be able to receive calls even if App runs in background. So i tried to implement Broadcast Receiver in other way (not in Activity but in Manifest). So deleted:

```
     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.addAction("android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL");
    callReceiver = new IncomingCallReceiver();
    this.registerReceiver(callReceiver, filter);
```

and Added in Manifest

```
          <intent-filter>
             <action android:name="android.SipDemo.INCOMING_CALL"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

But now it doesnt work, incomingCall is always null.

Before change, BroadcastReceiver got

```
context ==  com.example.android.sip.WalkieTalkieActivity@4051c5e8
```

and after change

```
context == android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@4058ac48
```

Maybe this is problem, but anybody has idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You should move the `SipProfile` stuff out of your activity and into a service. Your BroadcastReceiver `onReceive()` can then start the service and have it handle the call. The `context` you get in `onReceive()` is short-lived and you can only do certain things with it.

Comment: sir, can you explain a bit more deeper about moving `SipProfile` to service

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials on how to use services in Android, or buy yourself a book. I'm happy to answer specific technical questions for free but I'm not going to write your project for you (or do your homework for your) for free.